# What's the probability that a table has three couples?

Tags: probability

There are many questions (and answers) about couples sitting at a round table, but this one is different so hear me out.

Say 18 marries couples (so 36 people altogether) go to a dinner party and they are randomly assigned seats at 6 tables - 6 people at each table. What's the probability that at least one of the tables happens to have three couples?

A little context: I teach a college class of 36 students where we did a group project in pairs. Everyone was assigned a partner. Later in the semester, we went to lunch together when someone noticed one table happened to have three pairs. We thought to ourselves, this must be an incredibly rare occasion! I want to know how rare this is hence the question.

I can't figure out if this is a problem that can be solved using knowledge from an intro-level college stats class, or if it requires something more advanced. I can probably write a few lines of codes in R to simulate 10 millions assignments and find an approximation to the answer, but what's the math solution?

Edit: I wrote a small simulation program in R to do random seat assignment for one million times and calculate the probability that at least one table has three pairs. The answer seems to be around 0.2% or 0.002, but I'm not getting closer to the mathematical answer. The following codes create many 6 x 6 matrixes and count the number of pairs in each row (table).

```
n <- 1000000
j <- 0
for (i in 1:n) {
  m <- matrix (sample (0:35), nrow = 6, ncol = 6) %/% 2
  R1 <- sum (duplicated (m [1, ]))
  R2 <- sum (duplicated (m [2, ]))
  R3 <- sum (duplicated (m [3, ]))
  R4 <- sum (duplicated (m [4, ]))
  R5 <- sum (duplicated (m [5, ]))
  R6 <- sum (duplicated (m [6, ]))
  if (R1 == 3 | R2 == 3 | R3 == 3 | R4 == 3 | R5 == 3 | R6 == 6) {
    j <- j + 1
    }
}
paste ("In", n, "parallel universes,", j, "of them have at least one 3-pair table with a probability of", j/n)
```

Comment: Please show the own attempt to solve the problem, providing "context" is a must. See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question (Please tell us for instance which is the source of the problem, why is this interesting, how can one attack the problem combinatorially, or at least some Monte-Carlo simulation should be given...)

Comment: So we need the probability for the event that after a random placement of the $18$ pairs at the $6$ tables **at least one** table has three pairs? (In contrast to *exactly one* table...)

Comment: I was thinking of just one of the six tables has three couples, any one. Just to start on the easy side. I should be able to figure out the probability of "at least one" from there.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around.  It's easier to figure out "at least one" than it is to figure out "exactly one."

Comment: OK, I have updated the question to be at least one.